# Why is rewriteRule in httpd.conf not working on this Apache proxy server?

Tags: mod-rewrite, proxy

I recognize that this question is similar to others on this site. I have spent days reading these posts and trying different approaches. None has worked.

I am trying to use an Apache proxy server to map a particular URL to a new URL. I have a dedicated device (Black Box) on a local network which makes calls to original.remoteHost1.com. I wish to use the Apache proxy server on this local network to substitute new.remotehost2.com for original.remoteHost1.com when Black Box requests service. I am able to configure Black Box to point to the proxy server but Black Box does not expose an interface to change its target host for the HTTP service requests.

Black Box makes only two very specific requests:

1. http://original.remoteHost1.com/rectrack/file_name.php?data_1=text_string_1
2. http://original.remoteHost1.com/rectrack/file_name.php?data_1=text_string_1&data_2=text_string_2

which I wish to change to:

1. http://new.remotehost2.com/rectrack/file_name.php?data_1=text_string_1
2. http://new.remotehost2.com/rectrack/file_name.php?data_1=text_string_1&data_2=text_string_2

Acting as a proxy, the Apache server accepts the Black Box requests and forwards them to original.remoteHost1.com. I expected that I would be able to use rewriteRule in httpd.conf to change original.remoteHost1.com to new.remotehost.com, but I cannot get this seeming simple function to work.

I have tried using the following rewriteRule (as well as many variations) to substitute new.remotehost.com for original.host.com, but I can't seem to get Apache to actually make the substitution:

```
LoadModule rewrite_module modules/mod_rewrite.so
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} original.remoteHost1.com
RewriteRule   ^(.*)  http://new.remotehost2.com/$1 [P]
```

Does anyone have any idea why the new URL is not substituted for the original?

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve this problem. I don't recall why I tried this and I certainly don't know why it works. I'm running Windows 7. In the folder C:\Windows\System32\Drivers\etc\ is a file named "hosts". In that file, in a section related to localhost name resolution, I added the line:

```
127.0.0.1   original.remoteHost1.com
```

After doing this, the rewriteCond and rewriteRule acted as I had expected them to.